# How to ensure my Wordpress plugin's styling isn't overwritten by global / theme style?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

It's quite simple. I'm working on my first WordPress plugin. Testing on multiple WordPress websites, it seems that it's quite hard to make sure my plugin looks the same on all websites.

I obviously don't want to list every single possible css setting and write `none !important`.

So what's the right approach here?

Comment: plugin aim is to define and works with data. and theme aim is to display data. then I'm not sure to understand your question. edit your question to add more details, an example...

Comment: Hi Kaperto. I'm writing a plugin. My plugin, for example, has many buttons. I find that on one website, my button will be blue. On another it will be red. Another one will add a underline effect on hover. I'm not sure how to make sure it looks the same on all websites.

Answer (score 2):

While creating any plugin, you can make a common prefix according to your plugin name and add it everywhere. Like if i am creating a plugin i.e. "custom post type" then i will use "cpt" as a class or id on everywhere.
[image]

Just use unique prefix according to your plugin name so it will not conflict with theme styling.
Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you. I am doing that already. Though I find various "surprises" like seeing that my button has a random underline effect on some website. Am I supposed in my CSS to write "text-decoration:none" and basically anticipate and add "none" for all possible effects, because I can never know what global styles a website will have? I hope you understand my question

Answer (score 1):

Use could use custom HTML tags. So instead of this:

```
<div class="hello">Content</div>
```

Do this:

```
<my_element class="hello">Content</my_element>
```

That's the only way to be 100% sure, without using lots of over-qualifying things like !important etc.

Both are 'incorrect' ways that invalidate 'guidelines'.

But it will work, and it'll be fine forever as long as your tags are uniquely named and never become part of a spec and get treated in a predefined way by browsers.

For input fields etc, unfortunately you'll have to go with standard CSS selectors and qualify them more than any other CSS which may be present.

```css
asdf{
    display:block;width:100px;height:100px;background:black;color:white;
}
```

```html
<asdf>Hello!</asdf>
```

Comment: Hi Greggers. Thanks for the on-point answer. While I see how that would work, my goal for this plugin is to be accepted on CodeCanyon / Wordpress Repository, and I think they probably wouldn't accept that approach. I'm looking at Imagify (by WP Rocket) and I see they use a lot of !important and a custom class for everything, so perhaps I should do it like that....

Comment: Hi @StefanS , I'd be surprised if the Envato ecosystem would reject something based on invalid HTML tags, as they're actually used quite a lot. They are also becoming used by the big-boys and nodded to in various specs as they help facilitate things like web components. See: https://blog.usejournal.com/web-components-will-replace-your-frontend-framework-3b17a580831c 

The sole naming suggestion be that you use a hypen somewhere in them to namespace them and avoid conflicts with native html elements.

Comment: That's a very interesting point. I'll read through the link you posted. Thanks for the info